# Bibliography integration into TeXstudio

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I have a bib file called references.bib containing the following

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Online{LORAWAN2019,
  author  = {ABI Research},
  title   = {LORAWAN® AND NB-IOT: COMPETITORS OR COMPLEMENTARY?},
  date    = {10.06.2019},
  url     = {https://lora-alliance.org/sites/default/files/2019-06/cr-lora-102_lorawanr_and_nb-iot.pdf},
  urldate = {29.11.2019},
}
```

and a tex file in the same folder containing:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}

\cite{LORAWAN2019}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

I am editing in TeXstudio where I configured the "Default Bibliography Tool" to BibTeX. When I compile though, I only get `[?]`. What am I doing wrong? [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bcwrgtbttdbr) is an overleaf copy of the project  :)

**Edit** - This is the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.11.25)  5 DEC 2019 16:38
entering extended mode
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrreprt.cls"
Document Class: scrreprt 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script document class (report)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbasic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box27
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 137.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrreprt)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 241
7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrsize11pt.clo"
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package: typearea 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count80
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1716.
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@chapter=\count82
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip47
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\chapter on input line 5525.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip48
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5535.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5535.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip49
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrreprt)           for `\part on input line 5544.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5554.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5554.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip51
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5564.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5564.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5574.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5574.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5584.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5584.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip54
\belowcaptionskip=\skip55
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box28
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 6808.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip56
\c@figure=\count88
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 6825.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip57
\c@table=\count89
Class scrreprt Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 6994.
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \contentsname on input line 2.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listfigurename on input line 2.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listtablename on input line 2.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `LORAWAN2019' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.

(document.bbl) [1

{C:/Users/bruno/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (document.a
ux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2817 strings out of 492450
 61283 string characters out of 3129748
 273942 words of memory out of 3000000
 7239 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4248 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 43i,6n,72p,10085b,246s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 18092 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Did you run `bibtex document.tex`?

Comment: I couldn't open file name `document.tex.aux'

Comment: koppor made a typo, it should be just `bibtex document.aux` (often you can omit the `.aux`). Note that your title of this question is misleading. Jabref only manage the `.bib` file, it has nothing to do with the rest of the bibliography processing.

Comment: You mention that you use `texstudio`, it its normal configuration it will run latex and bibtex automatiscally. Is the `.bib` file explicitly named `references.bib` not `references.bib.tex`? (you seem to be on windows and windows has a tendency to hide file extensions by default).

Comment: @daleif I get "I couldn't open file name `document.aux'" no matter if I type "bibtex document" or "bibtex document.aux". The references.bib file has the type "BibTeX". FYI check out the overleaf link! Might be easier to check whats up :)

Comment: Hehe, you need a bibliography style, there is no default, try adding `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. Then it compiles just fine on overleaf

Comment: huh. Thanks! You can put that down as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of the title of the question should probably be changed as jsbref is not related to this, plus its only job is to edit the bib file, it is not involved in the further process.

I'm wondering whether you've fallen victim of editors parsing log files in a bad manner.

The only thing wrong with the mwe is a missing bibliography style, try adding

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Then run latex + bibtex + latex + larex if 6our editor doesn't already do this for you.

My reason for thinking about editors parsing log files is that bibtex will give a clear warning if the bibliography style is missing. But you'll never see this information if your editor hides it from you.

Comment: As I do lately, I'd recommend here to use `latexmk` or `arara`, if it fits the pipeline. This way, the multiple calls are automatized, in case of `latexmk` the script "guesses" the programs to call, so, e.g., `makeindex` will be included in the calls, if it is needed.

Comment: @OlegLobachev the few times I've used texstudio it has been quite good at guessing how many time to run latex and bibtex. That said I normally compile using latexmk in pvc mode

Comment: Well, I trust the most answerers to know about `latexmk`, but quite many those asking questions here might not. This was thought to be less a way to break the news of `latexmk` to you, but rather to mention it to the wide audience. Sorry, if it was offensive of misleading.

Comment: @OlegLobachev no problem, one bad thing with latexmk is that it is slow to start up on windows. I don't use arara as I don't have Java installed